# Why Multiple Linear Regression performs much better than Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, linear-regression

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3iyB.png]

I used two methods to try to solve this: neural network (NN) and multi-linear regression (MLR). The prediction results using MLR massively outperform NN. I tried almost everything with the NN, such as grid search to find the optimal "settings", and a lot of trial and error, but still couldn't get the model to perform.

(blue lines are predictions and orange lines are the targets), a perfect model would fit the two lines perfectly.

Results using MLR:

[image]

Results Using NN:

[image]

I'm not really looking for an answer to fix the NN, but more of an explanation of why this might happen.

Comment: you nn does not seem to be converged

Comment: Why are you using different test sets between the two methods? The target values in the test data for the NN model appears to have a completely distribution (mostly lying between 0.0 and 0.5) from that used for the LR model (target values here are mostly between 0.5 and 1.0)

Comment: If you have the same validation set, it's impossible that the NN underperforms compared to LR unless it overfits. A NN is like LR with added complexity

Comment: @DavidHarris, I did have the same test set for the two models. it was my mistake that i posted the other set i used for validation. I edited the question and posted the correct image. I hope it brings more clarity to the problem.

Comment: OK, I don't think there's enough info for a definite answer. You should be able to replicate LR in a neural net, by using a single Dense unit, and mean_squared_error loss. That might be a good starting point for understanding how more complex networks are behaving. And I still wonder whether you seem to be saying here that your validation set has a different distribution from your test set - these should usually be drawn from the same distribution.

Comment: @DavidHarris, to give a bit more light to the problem, this is a prediction to replicate a numeric model of an aircraft engine maintenance program. And in some of the independent variables,  if one increases, the other would also increase due to the nature of engine operations causing some degree of multicollinearity. Does that have anything to do with the poor performance of the NN model? But shouldn’t the MLR predictions also be off if that’s the case?

Comment: @DavidHarris I have tried using a single dense unit and MSE as the loss but the NN model still performs poorly and couldn’t even get close to the predictions of the MLR model. I can’t seem to understand why. I used Adam as the optimizer with a learning rate of 0.001 and ReLu as the activation function. There are about 3000 lines of learning data with 100 epochs, a batch size of 10 and Early Stopping with a patience of 10.

Comment: Not a *programming* question - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: Maybe try standardizing your inputs to the NN model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into overfitting or bias/variance tradeoff. Generally, more complex models require a lot more data to train on. If you have too few data points then the model will memorize the data set rather than learn the pattern in there